# add data to URL QR code?

Tags: url, qr-code

Is it possible to create a QR code that holds URL + data (numbers) that I can decode from my own app?

Also, I need it in such a way that if someone tries to scan it from a regular QR scanner it will only direct to the URL.

I am reading QR cards on my application to read data (there are few cards in different locations so reading the QR will tell me where the person is).

But I also want to do that if someone that does not have my app and randomly sees the QR code and tries to scan it with normal QR scanners it will redirect him to my app's URL..

Is this possible?

I tried something like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/<myapp> 123
```

and I simply seperate the first string from the second string to read the `123`

But when I scan it with a QR reader it redirects to a broken link..

Comment: Ok what language are we using here?

Comment: I'm writing android app but I don't think its related to the app.. its more related to the QR code method or URLs operation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify what programming language you are using.

Anyways, a solution would be to use GET parameters to be read by your app and not by the site.

Example:

```
www.yoursite.com/?location=Boston
```

If your app can read the variable `location` than you are good to go.
Of course the site will have to ignore it.

Comment: Thats working really good! I created php file with redirecting as:


`header("Location: http://mylink/");
exit;`

and I can simply add ? and data after it like you said and they all direct to the same php file..

Comment: @YardenCohen yep. Exactly. Good job